# Need help creating a new page on my ruby-based website

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5

I posted this a little while ago but have tried everything and still cannot create a new page on my website.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the 3 steps for making a new route/page with ruby is:

1. Add an empty function/controller action in `app/controllers/pages_controller`: `def "page name" end`
2. Add a corresponding view file: ex: `touch app/views/pages/page_name.html.erb`
3. Then add `get 'page_name', to: 'pages#page_name'` in `config/routes.rb`

I have tried this with 2 separate names and neither result in a new page/route being created. Am I missing some sort of terminal command or something? When I do `rails routes` it shows the other paths I've created such as `offerings`, but not `public_speaking` (I also tried to make a `test` path by following the 3 steps and that didn't show up either).

My code:

## Pages Controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  # GET request for / which is our home page
  def home 
    @basic_plan = Plan.find(1)
    @pro_plan = Plan.find(2)
  end 
      
  def about
  end 
      
  def offerings
  end 
      
  def public_speaking
  end
end
```

## Routes.rb

Then in `routes.rb` I tried using the same process (Adding `get 'public_speaking'`, to : `pages#public_speaking`)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "pages#home"
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
  resources :users do 
    resource :profile
  end 
  
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  resources :contacts, only: [:create]
  get 'contact-us', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'new_contact' 
  get 'offerings', to: 'pages#offerings'
  get 'public_speaking', to: 'pages#public_speaking'
end
```

## View file

I also created a file `public_speaking.html.erb` in the views folder with the same name.

I expected there to be a new route created (since it worked for `offerings` and `about`), however it has not worked and I'm not sure why. I will be repeating this process for 5-6 pages, so I want to be sure I can do it right

Please let me know if any other code location could be the issue here and I will provide whatever code.

Comment: Can you try `rake routes` and check what path is coming for your actions `public_speaking` and `offerings` and is your `about` working ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your page should be in views/pages/public_speaking.html.erb I will create in first case the controller with rails tools:

```
➜ rails g controller Pages home about offerings public_speaking
Running via Spring preloader in process 31236
      create  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
       route  get 'pages/home'
get 'pages/about'
get 'pages/offerings'
get 'pages/public_speaking'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/pages
      create    app/views/pages/home.html.erb
      create    app/views/pages/about.html.erb
      create    app/views/pages/offerings.html.erb
      create    app/views/pages/public_speaking.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/pages_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/pages.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/pages.scss
```

It creates all the things you need, then go to `app/views/pages` and you will see all the generated html.erb templates, then inside the template write teh static http page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Public Speaking</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is my page</h1>
    <p>I thinks that this should work!!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then start your rails app

rails server -p 5000

and go to http://localhost:5000/pages/public_speaking.html, you will have your static page there

[image: sample web page]

Comment: Thanks so much. I am a little confused. Is the top line what I type into the terminal and some of the rest in the .rb file or what? Are they all meant to be typed in the terminal?

Comment: The first code is, a shell command and output, the second one is the html code that you need to add to the app/views/pages/public_speaking.html.erb, Please if this help consider to check this answer

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This was the result:

Comment: Running via Spring preloader in process 3697

    conflict  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

Overwrite 

/home/ubuntu/environment/saasapp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm] 

       force  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
       route  get 'pages/public_speaking'
       route  get 'pages/offerings'
       route  get 'pages/about'
       route  get 'pages/home'
      invoke  erb
       exist    app/views/pages
    conflict    app/views/pages/home.html.erb


Should I overwrite?

Comment: I figured it out! All I had to do was replace the routes.rb code from "get 'public_speaking', to: 'pages#public_speaking'" to "get 'home/public_speaking'  and now I can view and link to that page!

Comment: Nevermind it just cleared my home page ugh. I'm not understanding what is wrong